# Code Golf Pro Golfer Least Swings Calculator

Tags: code-golf, simulation

## Your Challenge:

For a golf Course Of Inputted 'n' length to hole where:

```
'n' is a whole number and a multiple of 5 between 150 and 500 
and
1 integer in code = 1 metre
```

You must calculate the least amount of swings it can be completed in using a combination of clubs and ranges.

Here is a visual representation of what this calculator will be working out (in colours):
[image: 1]
Disregarding nature and swing paths, you are to find the fewest number of swings.

Firstly, you must have a 'Men Or Women' Option as shown in the pseudocode below:

```
INPUT <- "Men Or Women"
```

Each club option has Two Values. These are the ranges of the distance in which the club's shot may fall. This calculator assumes the player is a pro and can choose how far the shot goes in the range.
~It can only be in multiples of 5~

Higher towards the range of one club overrules Lower towards the range of another.

```
Club       Men     Women
Driver  200-260   150-200
3-wood  180-235   125-180
5-wood  170-210   105-170
2-iron  170-210   105-170
3-iron  160-200   100-160
4-iron  150-185    90-150
5-iron  140-170    80-140
6-iron  130-160    70-130
7-iron  120-150    65-120
8-iron  110-140    60-110
9-iron   95-130    55-95
PW       80-120    50-80
SW       60-100    40-60
putter   10-30     10-20
```

The input must ask for course length and gender separately, and then calculate and then display the output, which must start with displaying gender, and then look like a list (in order of the clubs to be used and the distance hit.

The final Value Must Be A Putter Distance implying it has

EG:

```
(Gender):

(n)m Course

Driver (x)m
4-iron (x)m
3-iron (x)m
putter (x)m
```

Please Be Aware This is just an example as it could include any combination of clubs.

## Finally:

If there is more than one answer, then all must be displayed with a title above exclaiming the answer like so:

```
(Gender):

(n)m Course

Run 1:

Driver (x)m
4-iron (x)m
3-iron (x)m
putter (x)m

Run 2:

Driver (x)m
4-iron (x)m
3-iron (x)m
putter (x)m
```

and so on...

Comment: Please be aware, except at weekends, I am unable to check comments between 0800 and 1600 GMT. If you leave one, I will get back to you as soon as I can